# use custom methods for sorting in rails .sort!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

I have am serving up a bunch of objects into a status feed and want to sort them based off their latest activity. If I were just sorting off of the created_at attribute of each object I would use the code:

```
    articles = Article.all
    documents = Document.all
    @feeds = (articles + documents).sort! { |b, a| a.created_at <=> b.created_at }
```

But let's say that people can post in documents such that the latest activity in a document is the created_at attribute in the latest post. Then I would like to sort as such:

```
 @feeds = (articles + documents).sort! { |b, a| a.latest_activity <=> b.latest_activity }
```

And I would define latest_activity in the models:

In Document.rb

```
 def latest_activity
      self.posts.last.created_at
 end
```

in Article.rb

```
 def latest_activity
     self.created_at
 end
```

This doesn't work.. the local server serves the following error:

```
 undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I accomplish the sorting desired here?

Comment: Shot in the dark-- Documents with no posts results in `self.posts.last` being `nil`?

Comment: self.posts.last.try(:created_at)

Comment: hmmmm Platinum Azure, good job - totally forgot to add a check for documents with no posts!!!

Comment: if you want to write it as an answer, i'll check-mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally use the "updated_at" rather than created_at. Then, in your Post class:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document, :touch => true
end
```

This means that when a post is saved, it will update the document's updated_at column.

Then, to simplify:

```
articles = Article.all
documents = Document.all
@feeds = (articles + documents).sort_by(&:updated_at)
```